# Online radio logo feedback request

Tags: logo, critique, branding, kerning

I'm working on a new logo concept for my online radio station and would like to receive feedback about the following:

1. Is the kerning/spacing appropriate?
2. Do you find the symbol appealing, unique and memorable?
3. Do you find a heavy resemblance with the Beats logo?

Any other kind of feedback will be very appreciated. Many thanks!

[image: Logotype concept]

Comment: Ooohh...be careful, [I've seen something like this before](https://www.beatsbydre.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's the Beat's by Dre logo

[image]

The logo isn't memorable and is frankly a rehash of every online radio site ever.

- Headphone/mic? ***Check***
- Radio "waves" ***Check***
- Trendly smooth gradient? ***Check***

I don't get anything "blur" about it and I don't see why I would be enticed to use your site. Is it fast? Faster than what's already out there?

Focus on an original shape or one that more accurately represents your name.

Comment: Thanks @Ovaryraptor for your honest feedback! I'm not able to up vote your answer. Thank you anyways.